# WP_Query - Accessing MetaValue from Query Result

Tags: wp-query, post-meta

Have this code. In doing a var_dump the meta_value is being retrieved under public object meta_value. I'm trying to access this data in a "WordPress" away instead of a more traditional PHP way.

What is the most efficient/best practice way of getting this meta value data?

The end goal is to get an array like:

```
array(
    [0]=>array("post_title"=>"title of post", "img_url"=>"url.com")
)
```

Thanks!

```
global $post;
//Get all products, id, name, and thumbnail image
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'ral-profile',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array( 'key' => '_thumbnail_id')
    )
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        //post actions
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: LIke [`get_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) ?

Comment: I'm not sure if get_post_meta() will requery the DB. Since it's already in the wp_query result, I just need to access that result.

Comment: Post Meta isn't queried in the WP_Query. WP_Query queries the `wp_posts` table and post meta is stored in the `wp_postmeta` table. You have to make a secondary call to get post meta which is what the `get_post_meta()` function is for.

Comment: So `'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => '_thumbnail_id'))` in the wp_query args is not included in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WP_Query()` only queries posts from the `wp_posts` table. Even if you add additional parameters such as:

```
'meta_query' => array( 
    array( 
        'key'     => '_thumbnail_id'
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    )
)
```

It looks at the `wp_postmeta` table to ensure that the posts it pulls has the post_meta `_thumbnail_id` but it **does not** also pull the post meta. The query **only** pulls post data from the `wp_posts` table. WordPress has a ton of useful functions to get ahold of this information though:

- [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) pulls and displays the post thumbnail in an `<img/>` tag.
- [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) - Still pulls the post thumbnail in an `<img/>` tag but does not display it. Allows you to store it into a variable for later use.

To achieve what you're trying to do we first have to get the `ID` of the post-thumbnail, then get the URL:

```
$thumb_id        = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, 'medium', true );
$thumb_url       = $thumb_url_array[0];
```

You can switch out `medium` with whatever size you need for the post thumbnail.

- [Quick Reference ( CSS Tricks )](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/get-featured-image-url/)

---

Alternatively, you could use [`get_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to get the thumbnail ID ( or any other post meta values ):

```
$thumb_id        = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', true );
$thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, 'medium', true );
$thumb_url       = $thumb_url_array[0];
```

Comment: Phew! So use to straight PHP and frameworks - am getting use to the WP way of doing things. Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem! You can view the entire Query Object by printing it out: `print_r( $the_query );` but note that only parameters in the `posts` index can be accessed in "The Loop's" `$post` object. The other indexes are explained via [Methods & Properities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods_and_Properties) in the Codex.

Comment: Sweet that link is exactly what I was looking for! I've just been going through the github repo to understand what is going on b/c sometimes the codex is a bit lacking - but that is super helpful. Thanks again!